# Determine npm or yarn script run from module

Tags: node.js, npm, argv, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

Lets say I have the following scripts in my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "start": "node index.js",
  "start-with-flag": "node index.js -f"
}
```

Inside`index.js` I have a `console.log(process.argv)`, and the scripts above output the following:

```
$ npm run start
[ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.4.0/bin/node',
  '/Users/.../test_app/index.js' ]

$ npm run start-with-flag
[ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.4.0/bin/node',
  '/Users/.../test_app/index.js',
  '-f' ]
```

Is it possible to retrieve the value of the scripts which I ran (`start` or `start-with-flag`) inside of `index.js`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the script which is currently executed with the [npm_lifecycle_event](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#current-lifecycle-event) environment variable.

*command*

```
$ npm run start-with-flag
```

*index.js*

```
console.log(process.env.npm_lifecycle_event)  // start-with-flag
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "start-with-flag": "node index.js -f"
  }
}
```